# Python ran as a script or module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I know if my script is being run as a standalone script or module? Because I need to do something different in my code if it is being run as a standalone script.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #stuff you want to do as a standalone script
```

The interpreter checks whether the script is the main file that's running. If it's being imported then the part in the `if` block won't execute.